# Date or Year matching in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3.x . I have a post request for DOB where user can input either a year in YYYY format or Date in DD/MM/YYYY format 
is there a way to validate if the user has inputed the DOB in required format or else prompt him to enter the DOB in right format.
I am using regex

```
    if  re.match( "\d{4}", dob_check):
        client_dob = dob_check
    elif datetime.datetime.strptime(dob_check, "%d%d/%m%m/%Y%Y%Y%Y"):
        client_dob = dob_check
    else :
        return return_aadhar_date_format
```

when i input 1891 it correctly fetch the DOB as well if i enter digits more than 5 it doesn't take it.
but when i enter 3 digit or less than that it throws an re.error

> re.error: redefinition of group name 'd' as group 2; was group 1

.but i want to prompt the user to enter the DOB in right format.it's not an exception its some package error.
Also when i enter DOB in 12/12/2000 it throws an re.error as my guess is it goes to the first if block and the execution stops there.

Below are my approaches

```
    if len(dob_check) == 4:
        client_dob = dob_check
    elif datetime.datetime.strptime(dob_check, "%d/%m/%Y"):
        client_dob = dob_check
    else :
        return correct_format
```

second :

```
    if len(dob_check) == 4:
        try :
            if len(dob_check) == 4:
              client_dob = dob_check  
            else:
                return correct_format
        except:
            return correct_format
    elif datetime.datetime.strptime(dob_check, "%d/%m/%Y"):
        client_dob = dob_check
    else :
        return correct_format
```

Comment: `.strptime(dob_check, "%d%d/%m%m/%Y%Y%Y%Y"):` is incorrect. You mean `.strptime(dob_check, "%d/%m/%Y"):`. But to catch a string that doesn't match that format, you'll need an exception handler

Comment: You say that it throws an re.error.  Include the actual error in your question.  Also, are you using python 3 or 2.7?  Please update the tags accordingly.

Comment: @roganjosh sorry i changed it to %d/%m/%Y but i also want to include only the year YYYY to check the validation.

Comment: You don't need regex for any of this. Just `try`/`except`. if the string is of length 4, try convert to an integer and check it is greater than 1900 and less than 2019 (if you're expecting newborns to sign up)

Comment: @roganjosh i can't put an year range.Also even if i enter abcd it accepts it for the DOB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `strptime` for both validations?

Edit: It's been pointed out to me that it never reaches the `full_time` check if it is indeed a match, so here's yet another attempt.

```
def is_datetime_match(s, pattern):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(s, pattern)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

if is_datetime_match(dob_check, '%Y') or is_datetime_match(dob_check, '%d/%m/%Y'):
    client_dob = dob_check:
else:
    return incorrect_format
```

Comment: because when i enter alphabets it takes that and the else block doesn't gets executed

Comment: @DataDoctor I've replaced the if statement with a try/catch block

Comment: It should read `except ValueError` instead of `catch ValueError`

Comment: @blueteeth problem with this piece of code is that it always goes to the except block even if the DOB is in proper DD/MM/YYYY format

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the below code

```
if  re.match( "^[1-9]\d{3}$", dob_check):
        client_dob = dob_check     
elif re.findall(r"[\d]{2}/[\d]{2}/[\d]{4}", dob_check):
        client_dob = dob_check
else :
      return incorrect_format
```

Comment: when i enter 18832 ,it doesn't go to the else block unfortunately,i want the last else block to get executed to prompt the user to enter the correct format

Comment: it also executes dd/m/yyyy dates as well and skips the else block

Comment: changed to (r"[\d]{2}/[\d]{2}/[\d]{4}", dob_check) for dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: it can also be an solution with some minor tweaks!

Comment: @DataDoctor thanks for your suggestions I have updated my answer.

Comment: the problem with your code is ,if i enter a number more than 4 digits it accepts that value instead of going to the else block, also re.match( "^[1-9]\d{4}$", dob_check) changed to match 4 digits only

Comment: it also takes DOB in DDD/MMMMM/YYYYYY format instead of going to the else block